# Newline in sed pattern for a c/c++ function

Tags: logging, replace, sed, str-replace

I want to call a trace/log function in the start of all the function in all files under given folder.
An example,

**from**

```
void getVal(int a) 
{
   return mArray[a];
}
```

**To**

```
void getVal(int a) 
{pr_debug();
   return mArray[a];
}
```

So, i tried as below, but did not work.
find soc -type f -exec sed -i 's/)\n{\n/)\n{pr_debug()\n/g' {} \;

I searched and tried other ways, but no luck.

```
find soc  -exec sed -i 's/)\
> {\
> /)\
> {pr_debug();\
> /g' {} \;


find soc -type f -exec sed -i "s/)\\`echo -e '\n\r'`{\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/)\\`echo -e '\n\r'`{pr_debug()\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/g" {} \;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 'N; s/)[ ]*\n{/&\npr_debug();/g'
```

**(OR)**

```
sed '/(.*)[ ]*$/{N; s/)[ ]*\n[ ]*{/&\npr_debug();/g}'
```

**Explanation:**

```
N                  - will read next line and append
s/pattern/replace/ - normal substitution takes place
&                  - will replace with what exactly matched in pattern
```

**EDIT**:
the find command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/(.*)[ ]*$/{N; s/)[ ]*\n[ ]*{/&\npr_debug();/g}' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. It worked. But I don't exactly get how it works.. :)

Comment: I understood your command now. And just checked that, it has not replaced in all the occurrences.. some placed it has replaced and other places it had left as it is. So, I'm seeing what is the problem..!

Comment: @BalamuruganA, Still if you face problem, See the update ( another `sed` ).

Comment: Excellent.. It works well. Thanks. I updated the command i used.